# How to sync songs in Rhythmbox with an iPod

Tags: rhythmbox, ipod

I can sync them with Banshee but in Rhythmbox (Am starting again to use it since it will be the default in 12.04) I can see that Rhythmbox can detect the ipod and see the songs but when I try to drag one to the ipod how can I tell it to sync it so I can remove the iPod and listen to it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using iOS 5.x, the library that Rhythmbox (and others) use to do this does not yet support the newer database version. If your iOS device has recently been updated, then you simply need to wait for libimobiledevice to be updated (watch the [website](http://www.libimobiledevice.org/) under Music/Video Synchronization Status for updates).

[edit: 3/11/13 e.m.fields - **It seems that the libimobiledevices is supporting up to iOS 6.12 as of this release.** ]

from [www.libimobiledevice.org](http://www.libimobiledevice.org):

> Latest Release: 1.0.7
>   Development/Unstable Release: 1.1.4
>
> Tested with iPod Touch 1G/2G/3G/4G, iPhone 1G/2G/3G/3GS/4/4S/5, iPad 1/2/3rd Gen and Apple TV running up to firmware 6.1.2 on Linux, Mac OS X and Windows.

Comment: Thanks rwrw. For the moment I found this tool gtkpod which basically works. It detects the shuffle 4th gen I have and I can just drag, drop, sync and then listen to them with no problem.

Comment: It seems that the libimobiledevices is supporting up to iOS 6.12 as of this moment. However I have't been able to get it working with my rhythmbox installation, so YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can take a look on the official documentation here:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PortableDevices/iPhone#Syncing_with_Rhythmbox

This is a grafical hint on how to do this:

http://www.simplehelp.net/2007/07/03/how-to-manage-your-ipod-using-rhythmbox-in-ubuntu/

If this doesn't work, you can try as described in this guide:

http://ubuntu-install.blogspot.com/2011/04/connect-ipad-and-ipod-with-ubuntu.html

Comment: Yes I already dragged the song to the ipod and yes that works. I can see the song there but I can not sync it to the ipod and if I remove the ipod the song is not there. It only "shows" that is there, is not actually synced to the device. That is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a Toshiba NB505 with Ubuntu 12.10 and an iPod Nano 8GB 4th Gen.  I restored the iPod using iTunes on a separate windows computer for a clean slate.  I set up my playlists and podcasts in Rhythmbox, connected the iPod, and synced with library.  When trying to sync again the following day after downloading fresh podcast episodes, Rhythmbox would crash again, send an error report and I was back at square one.  After looking at many forum entries and deleting config files that were hidden, trying banshee, trying gtkpod, I could not fix the problem.  However if I restored the iPod in iTunes and synced with Rhythmbox back on my Ubuntu netbook, it would sync fine, but only once.  Here's my lame attempt at a fix.  I eventually used gtkpod to remove the songs and podcasts (right-click on the iPod in gtkpod and remove all songs, click "i'm sure"), then once the iPod is empty, close gtkpod, open Rhythmbox and sync with library or drop podcasts or music directly on to the iPod.  It has worked so far for me.  I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I think I see the problem:

- Ubuntu libimobiledevice version: 1.1.4
- Version that supports iOS 6.1.3: 1.1.5.

**Edit**: the above might not appear to make much sense, but it has been merged out of context from this question: [sync - iPhone 4s + Rhythmbox = Fail (12.10, ios 6.1.3) - Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/283021/iphone-4s-rhythmbox-fail-12-10-ios-6-1-3). In short, at time of writing, Ubuntu's version of libimobiledevice does not support the latest iOS.

Comment: I installed libimobiledevice 1.1.5 on ubuntu 12.10. I still could not sync my iphone 4s with 6.1.3 with rhythmbox.