# Ubuntu 12.04, music won't sync to iPod

Tags: sync, music, clipboard, ipod

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to sync songs in Rhythmbox with an iPod](https://askubuntu.com/questions/90027/how-to-sync-songs-in-rhythmbox-with-an-ipod)

I was looking for a solution to this online but couldn't find one.
I've been using rhythmbox for my iPod for a long time now, however in Ubuntu 12.04, in rhythmbox, when I drag a music file from my library to my iPod, where it would usually sync/copy across, nothing happens.

It is an iPod touch, I think it is the 3rd generation before/without the camera.

If anyone has any solutions to this or ideas of what to try please let me know.

Thank you, Paul