# iPhone 4s + Rhythmbox = Fail (12.10, ios 6.1.3)

Tags: 12.10, sync, rhythmbox, iphone

(This is emphatically *not* a double of this: [How to sync songs in Rhythmbox with an iPod](https://askubuntu.com/questions/90027/how-to-sync-songs-in-rhythmbox-with-an-ipod). I've tried everything there.)

Can't seem to control how to add music to an iPhone. It will either:

1. Try to rewrite the whole library to the iPhone, causing it to run out of space, or
2. If I drag music onto the iPhone icon, I get a progress bar and a lot of CPU activity, but no files are copied to the iPhone.

There are no error messages, and nothing related to the process in the kernel messages. Suggestions welcomed, please.